# Looping through remote data

Tags: javascript, php, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape some data from a website (a list of movies) - but the website only shows around 50 at a time and requires the user to click a button to load more. Is there a way I can script a click of this button or to loop through the data somehow? The website isn't on my server. (Trying to get a list of Sky Movies from the Virgin Media website)

http://anywhere.virginmedia.com/on-demand/browse/movies/

Answer (score 1):

The data are loaded using ajax, not just hidden, you'll need a web scraper to parse and trigger the click on the "load more" button till all data are displayed.

Check out [Goutte](https://github.com/fabpot/goutte), a PHP crawler used by Symfony.